# Separate out table results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 tables and I want to separate out the combined results for AF & CA. I'm sure where I am doing wrong. How can I separate out both the results?

```
def table(df):
    mylist = ["AF", "CA"]
    for item in mylist:
        if item == 'AF':
            df.append(item)
            return()
```

My data:

```
   Table1: 
   Col1     Col 2     Col3 
    AF       98        45
    CA       10       68
   Table2:
   Col1     Col 2     Col3 
    AF       2        45
    CA       100       6
```

Expected Output:

```
    Table for AF: 
   Col1     Col 2     Col3 
    AF       100        90
     Table for CA: 
    CA       110       74
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I appreciate that. I want separate results for both not combined in table. e.g seperate table for AF and table for CA. Another way that I was thinking to filtering out with AF and CA through a loop. Any suggestions what would be best to implement?

Comment: Yep, I just did. I read your mind mate =)

Comment: I think this will concat the results rather than separate it out

Comment: Check at the end of the answer.

Comment: thanks for the idea. This is helpful. Can you also suggest how can I do it while defining a function as I mentioned above in my question. The reason is that I have defined a big list of tables and trying to separate out the results.

Comment: BTW, you add comments here related with yor question and if you want to clarify an answer you should comment in the answer. Also if someone answer your question and it works for you accepted or upvote to show aprecciation if you choose someone else answer and also works for you.

Comment: Ohkk.. thanks for the clarification. I'm new here, will follow the directions as you've mentioned. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]) 
df_OUT = df.groupby('Col1', as_index=False).agg({'Col2':'sum', 'Col3':'sum'})
```

Output:

```
    Col1   Col2    Col3
0   AF     100     90
1   CA     110     74
```

If you want different dataframes, you can do:

```
df1_AF = df_OUT.loc[lambda df: df['Col1'] == 'AF']

# Output
    Col1   Col2   Col3
0   AF     100    90
```

Comment: thanks for the idea. This is helpful. Can you also suggest how can I do it while defining a function as I mentioned above in my question. The reason is that I have defined a big list of tables and trying to separate out the results.

Comment: Any suggestions? Please let me know how can I do it while defining a function